# C++ storing static methods of classes in unordered_map

Tags: c++, static-methods

I have a base class `Vehicle` and I want to populate an `std::unordered_map` with subclasses of `Runnable` (`Motorcycle`, `Car`, `Airplane`) such that I can iterate through the map and call static methods `Motorcycle::run()`, `Car::run()`, `Airplane::run()` in succession.

How should I populate the `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: What is the reason that you are doing this rather than using polymorphism?  There may be an easier/better way of doing what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Yes, specifying what you want to do exactly may really help finding a better solution.

Comment: From the information given it's almost guaranteed that there's a design problem, on one end you have instances of a class, but on the other hand you have static functions which you want to be able to call and thereby discard the object relation.

Comment: What's the problem? Don't you know how to populate an unordered_map at all (with any type of value), or is there some specific problem with populating it with function pointers or some wrapper of function pointers?

Comment: Static methods are type specific. The whole point of polymorphism is that you avoid having to know the type of the object. It seems you want to do two orthogonal things here.

Comment: In fact do you really mean `static` methods? Because it sounds like inheriting from `Runnable` means you want to call each subtype's overridden `run()` function. That would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches.

**The hard way:**

As static functions are not virtual, you would have to store a [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html) of `Mororcyle`, `Car` and `Airplane`.

```
typedef boost::variant< Motorcycle, Car, Airplane > VRunnable;  // variant 
unordered_map<key_t, VRunnable> m;
```

When you iterate through your `unorderd_map`, you may then identify the type of the object, and call the static member of the correct type.  You do this by using a visitor class that defines an operation overloaded fo reach type in the variant.

It works, but it's rarther tedious considering what you want to do.  In fact, you don't take any advantage of `Runnable` inheritance and polymorphism here.

**The smart way:**

The easier way would be to have a virtual member Runnable::vrun() that calls the approporiate static run() of each Runnable subclass.  Then you could simply iterate through your unorderd map, and call the virtual function:  the object would then call the correct static member.

```
unordered_map<key_t, Runnable> m;
for (auto x: m) 
    f.second.vrun();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can't polymorphically call a static method. However you can call a regular method and have *it* call the static method.

```
struct Runnable
{
    virtual void run_me() = 0;
};

class Car : public Runnable
{
public:
    virtual void run_me() { run(); }
    static void run();
};
```